# Добавление исключений IP в сервер PPTP?

Tags: debian, vpn, pptp

Можно ли добавлять исключения в данном типе сервера?
Если да, то как?

Comment: Я бы реализовал это через RADIUS или iptables

Comment: Пример с iptables можно?

Comment: Пример?.. Просто блокируете пакеты с блокируемых адресов на 1723-й порт.

Comment: То бишь, если я заблокирую пакеты, то они пойдут минуя pptp сервер?